# Bathroom with added shower wall hi

Tags: bathroom, walls, shower, planning

[image]building out bathroom and came across the plans with a 8” wall in the shower is required . at first I thought it was for plumbing then I looked at the bathroom across  the hall in a guest room it has the same kind of wall but the plumbing on the opposite side . realized this could be for aesthetic purpose .Does anyone know

Comment: I built many showers. Never had to have a wall 8" thick.  Most all plumbing will fit in a standard 2x4 wall cavity.  Are you talking about height...and mean 8 foot?

Comment: A shower usually requires three walls and a door or curtain.  Where does the 8 inch wall go?  Is the wall 8" thick or 8" high(for door/curtain)?

Comment: For what’s often known as a wet wall, you need a bit of depth to cut big holes through studs for drains and vents. Show us a drawing of both sides of the plumbing.

Comment: With the plans, it seems to be for a filler/spacer so the shower design fits.  If redoing the shower and wanted a longer one or wanted a tub, there should be no problem with removing that wall.  Unless they use that space for heating ducts or something not shown.

Answer (score 2):

That wall is there to give some relief between the shower and toilet. It is totally optional and could be removed to make the shower longer.  However making the shower base 60" rather than 48" you could be needing a custom build rather than a standard shower pan...if it matters.

Eliminating the wall would add 12" and a standard 60" shower door will fit nicely.  The trade off is the entire toilet is sitting right outside the shower.

( personal note: I would enjoy the larger shower.)

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that . RmDman

Comment: Alternately, you could use the extra 12" in the adjacent room for a built-in shelf or something.